# Bind9 basic configuration for internal network with windows pcs

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns, dhcp

I have a network with more than 50 PCs running on Windows, Mac ans Ubuntu. We have one internal Web Site running in a windows 8 PC IIS on the IP 192.168.0.110.

Right now we all can access this website by typing 192.168.0.110 in the browser address bar.But the current requirement is we need to access this website by simply typing the website name in the browser (www.internaltest.com). I think by using a Ubuntu PC with bind9 can do the work.

I tried to configure but i stuck with these two configurations. What are the configuration supposed to be here?? can anyone help me??
I don't want this website to be accessed from outside so this DNS server wants to be worked in internal network only.

-No domain name (if necessary we can give testing.com as domain name)

-Web server IP= 192.168.0.110  (Os Win8.1)

-Web site name= www.internaltest.com

-Web server name= tesingteam

-web server username= adminweb

-router ip= 192.168.0.1 (default gateway)

-Dns server ip= 192.168.0.19   (Os Ubuntu 14.04)

-Dns server name= dnsmaster

-Dns server username= admindns

With these data how these files suppose to be?

**1 Forward zone file

2 Reverse zone file**

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How do these computers connect to the network?  If they use DHCP to obtain name server etc. information, then just configure that to point to your DNS box, and you're pretty much done.  If they are each configured manually, you will need to update each manually.

Comment: Thats clear but, I am stuck with the creation of Forward/Reverse zone files. Can you help with that ??

Comment: Did you already try Google with results like http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch6/index.html#split-view?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [Ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns.html). It covers your exact case. It was the only reference I used when I setup your exact case on my LAN.